# OpenSSL wait until read data is available

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL to connect to a HTTPS server, send data and read response. I need to maintain connection open and to read data as soon as it is available.

I'm using BIOs, and read data with `BIO_read`.

The problem is that I wait on socket using `select()` but I can't be sure when there is DATA available to read or not.

I tried (after I make sure `select()` says there is data available for read):

- BIO_eof
- BIO_pending
- BIO_should_read
- SSL_pending
- SSL_peek

But it doesn't seem to work. `BIO_eof` returns false and I check for data with other functions, but for example `BIO_pending` returns false even if there is data available.

If I return true based on those functions, I get `SYSCALL_ERROR` so something is wrong.

How can I check if there is read data available on socket? I have to make sure that when `SSL/BIO_read` is called there IS data available to be read WITHOUT using those functions. Sure, I can use them, but without losing data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I wait on socket using select() but I can't be sure when there is DATA available to read or not.

Yes you can. If `select()` returns > 0 and there are `readfds` and no `writefds`, there are readable sockets. However the data read may be SSL data, not application data. You can't tell that in advance. You have to do the read to find out. The possibility remains that after doing so you may still have no data, or a requirement to write, etc, as advised by the API. You just have to cope with that.